# How to fade in text when a button is clicked in Adobe Edge Animate?

Tags: animation, adobe-edge

I'm learning to program with Adobe Edge Animate. How would I go about making a basic fade-in of text when a button is pressed?

Comment: I cleaned up your title a bit, and removed the unnecessary closing to your post. I shortened your introduction a bit as well, though it could use a bit of additional detail if you wouldn't mind explaining where you are in your learning process - specifically, what you already know must be done to accomplish this and what you're hoping to learn here. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to do this from the stage and are including jQuery from the scripts panel in the Library.

```
sym.$('btn1').bind('click', function () {

sym.$('textBlock').fadeOut();

});
```